# Is exposing a constant IV an easy target to attacks?

Tags: encryption, initialization-vector

I have multiple RFID tags which I want the data stored on them to only be read by certain users when scanned. What I did was basically to encrypt the data with a key using CBC mode, take the encrypted hex data and append it with the IV, and then put this whole string into the tag.

So, each tag will have a different IV but their data is encrypted by the same key.

Basically, **Tag A** is assigned with $IV_A$ and **Tag B** is assigned with $IV_B$, same for Tag C, D and so on. I would pre-encrypt the data on my computer, append the IV to the back of the encrypted data, and then transfer the whole string into the tags. The different data for each of the tags will all be encrypted with the *same* key. So, the data in **Tag A** would contain $EncryptedMsg_A+IV_A$. In **Tag B**, the data in it would look like $EncryptedMsg_B+IV_B$.

The IVs are appended in clear text behind the encrypted data. $IV_A$ will remain unchange as the IV of **Tag A** for as long as it is around. And $IV_B$ will remain unchange as the IV of **Tag B** too.

The users wouldn't be writing to the tag. They will only be reading from the tag.

However, the part where IV remain unchanged on each scan and exposed makes me feel uneasy about this method.

Will this method be sustainable to attackers? Should I have another key to encrypt the IV before appending to the encrypted data? Would it be stronger this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use CBC mode, you'll want to get a new, randomly-generated IV before each message encryption.  As long as you do this, you shouldn't have to worry about issues like how many times the same ciphertext is read with the same IV.

Comment: But in my case, since the tags are passive, they can't generate random IV on their own. What else can I do?

Comment: @xenon Since the tags are passive, what's performing the encryption operation?  I'd have guessed that something able to encrypt could also generate a random value.

Comment: @xenon Overall, the gist is to break the correlation between identical plaintext blocks to ciphertext blocks by XOR'ing the plaintext blocks with something.  CBC calls for doing this with random IV for the first block then using its results from later blocks, but you should be able to get this same basic effect other ways.  For example, CTR mode uses a nonce (which is constant, like you have) _plus_ a counter value that just iterates each time, ensuring that the effective-IV (nonce + counter) changes each time.  If you can't get random IV but can use a counter, CTR might work for you.

Comment: Basically, I'm "pre-encrypting" the data and storing the encrypted data onto the passive tags. So, the IV in the case of CBC or counter in the case of CTR would have been fixed. But this looks like a bad idea because after reading your answer, I figured the IV and counter should really be random or at least different each time. However, the tags are passive and they can't generate random numbers on their own. What else can I try for this problem?

Comment: @xenon I'm not sure if I'm following the situation.  So, hypothetically, say that you:  **(1)** Have a secret you want to store on a tag.  **(2)** Use a computer to encrypt the secret using CBC and random IV the computer creates.  **(3)**  Store the encrypted data + IV on the tag.  **[end]**  Are you able to do that, or if not, what's the barrier?

Comment: Yes, this is what I've done. However, in step **(3)**, the IV on the tag will be fixed because I pre-encrypted the data in **(2)**. Wouldn't this be an issue as you mentioned that the IV does need to vary?

Comment: @xenon As long as each message gets its own, random IV, it seems like it should be fine.  Is the problem that the IV is fixed on the tag, but a new message might be written onto the tag using the same IV?

Comment: @xenon In the question, you'd said "_This part where the IV are unchanged makes me feel uneasy about this method._"  What'd you mean by "the IV are unchanged"?  This is, unchanged between different tags with the same message, or unchanged over time on the same tag, or...?

Comment: Sorry, I should be been clearer on this. I've updated this part of my question. What I meant is the IV remain unchange on each of the tags. So each tags are kind of assigned with a fixed IV. The data on each of the tags is encrypted with their respective fixed IV.

Comment: @xenon Thanks for elaborating!  And given "_However, the part where IV remain unchanged on each scan and exposed makes me feel uneasy about this method._", I'd think that you should be good.  You need new, random IV for each message encryption, but it doesn't matter how many times the ciphertext (both encrypted data and IV) are read.

Comment: This discussion seems to identify an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) in the question - a proposed solution instead of actually stating the goal.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be describing a scenario where each tag has a constant message
In order to answer the question about security we need to understand what are you afraid of? 
If all you want is to prevnet the attacker from decrypting the data or retriving the key what you are saying sounds secure.
As you do not seem to be reusing the same IV to encrypt multiple messages but rather sending the same encrypted message with same IV multiple times. This does not give an attacker any more information then encrypting once.
It you add an HMAC could also get gurantees the encrypted content wasn't altered.
Whar you can not get in this sort of setup is protection against cloning or replay attacks which remain very possible. 
A different way of achieving same requirements which may work for you is not have data on the tag at all, just have a random unique ID and keep dictionary on the scanning side, in many cases this is simpler and obviously provides the security gurantees above.

If you would keep the same key and IV but replace the message that would be a security issue which can be severe in some cases or mild in others. For example it allows trivially detecting messages with a shared prefix.

If you want to prevent replay attacks or cloning a different IV won't suffice you will need some sort of challenge response or a time based key or something.